# SSRS Total by Type

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS. I have a report that goes like this

Type  Amount
A      500
B      200
A      100
C      400
C      200

I want to convert this to a report like this

Type  Total Amount
A      600
B      200
C      600

Basically get distinct Types on the left column and th totals for those types in the right column. Is there a way i can do that easily?

Thanks

Comment: Just group by Type, and do the Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) in the value box.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with you simple report which just lists the records in your DataSet:

Design:

[image: Simple Report Layout]

Results:

[image: Simple Report Results]

Right click on `(Details)`in the Row Groups section and choose `Add Group -> Parent Group`:

[image: Add Group]

Choose the field you want to group by (`Type` in our example) from the `Group by:` dropdown, choose to add either a group header or footer and click OK:

[image: Group By]

Your table will now look something like this:

[image: Table Pre Edits]

You can delete the second column and the third row - or second row if you chose to add a group footer earlier - entirely (clicking OK when deleting the row and being prompted to delete the associated group), leaving a layout like this:

[image: Table Post Edits]

Now just click the field selector for the empty cell in the table and choose your `Amount` field:

[image: Select Sum Amount 1]

or right click on the empty cell, choose Expression from the context menu and enter the following expression:

`=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)`

either of which should result in the formula being placed into the cell:

[image: Complete Layout]

Now run your report and you should get the expected result:

[image: Complete Result]

There's loads of places online with similar guides and resources which you can also consult:

- [MSDN Reporting Services Tutorial (Adding Grouping and Totals)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms170712.aspx)
- [MS TechNet (Calculating Totals and Other Aggregates)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630415(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [MSDN (Add a Total to a Group or Tablix Data Region)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239342.aspx)

There are also several other similar questions here on SO which you'll find if you just search for them.

Comment: Changing the detail row group to group by type should be enough. There is no need for creating the parent group. But nice answer anyway +1

Comment: @ChrisTian thanks for the pointer, I did wonder as I was writing it whether it was all a bit convoluted! It's just the way I've always done it, being self taught and just doing "what works". Thanks for the tip, I'll take the simpler approach next time I need to do this!